# Unexpected Javascript array behavior

Tags: javascript

I  signed the variable `bubbleL1` to `1`, but why the first variable in the `bubbles` list, which is `bubbleL1` still shows `undefined`? I know this maybe a stupid question, but I really don't know why.

```
    let bubbleL1, bubbleL2, bubbleL3, bubbleR1, bubbleR2, bubbleR3;
    let bubbles = [bubbleL1, bubbleL2, bubbleL3, bubbleR1, bubbleR2, bubbleR3];

    bubbleL1 = 1;
    console.log(bubbleL1) // 1
    console.log(bubbles) // [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

What I want is a list with a specific name for each item in it (for the declared reason, I really don't just use bubbles[0], bubbles[1]...)

Let's say we have a list named `bubbles`, and we also have six variables called `bubbleL1`, `bubbleL2`, `bubbleL3`, `bubbleR1`, `bubbleR2`, `bubbleR3`. I want to put all these six variables into the `bubbles` list, so later I can assign values to each variables that in the list, like this:

```
bubbles.forEach((bubble) => {
  bubble = "something";
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bubbleL1` is a primitive and therefore copied by value.

```js
let x = 3;

let sum = x;
sum = 3 + 5;

console.log(x); // 3
```

Objects and arrays, on the other hand, will exhibit your expected copy-by-ref behavior:

```js
let x = {a: 3};

let sum = x;
sum.a = 3 + 5;

console.log(x.a); // 8
```